# Can I name a variable as D(1,0,+1/2)?

Tags: variable

I am trying to use variables with names as D(0,0,0), D(1,1/2,+1/2), etc. but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: You're looking for trouble.

Comment: You can make some progress with `Subscript`, e.g., `Subscript[d, 1, 1/2, +1/2]` (`D` is a reserved symbol), but I agree with @Belisarius that you are looking for trouble.

Comment: Maybe you meant something like [indexed objects](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MakingDefinitionsForIndexedObjects.html)?

Comment: @bbgodfrey thanks it really helped : Subscript[D,"(1,0,+1/2)"]

Comment: If you want to have the `+` too, you could use `Subscript[d, 1, 1/2, HoldForm[+1/2]]`, but do be wary of potentially undesirable side effects.

Comment: Thanks again @bbgodfrey the plus sign already appears with the "(1,0,+1/2)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no.  `Symbols` can only contain letters and numbers, and must start with a letter.  For instance:

```
Symbol["D(1,0,+1/2)"]
```

Returns the error:

> > Symbol::symname: The string "D(1,0,+1/2)" cannot be used for a symbol name. A symbol name must start with a letter followed by letters and numbers.